# Purpose and use case of each type of Base64 in java 8

Tags: java, base64

How to know when to use which type (Simple , URL, MIME) of `Base64` in Java 8? I know the difference, but I want to know when to use which under what circumstance?

Comment: Maybe you could add a link to what you mean by (uppercase) Base64. I am only aware of the encoding/decoding mechanism named base64. Beyond that, typically, in software, you use a concept when you *need* it. Not because because you *can*, but because it makes sense to use it to solve some problem.

Comment: There is no "Simple" type - there is a "Basic" type. And you need Basic, unless you need one of the others because you are implementing a standard that requires you to use one of the others. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Answer (score 0):

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for the `Base64` class summarize the differences.  Based on that:

- If you are implementing a protocol specified by someone else, use the base64 variant that the spec calls for.
- Use MIME if you want or need the base64 encoded data to have lines of less than 80 characters.  (For example, RFC821 / RFC822 limit email bodies to 80 characters.)
- Use URL / File system safe if you intend to embed the Base64 encoded data is valid as a path component in a URL or file system pathname.
- Use Basic in other situations.